# Using Puppeteer Node library, how to get table data if there are 19 <table> elements with no unique identifiers on the page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

My goal is to get the  textContent of a `<table>` element using Puppeteer Node Library. There are 19 `<table>` elements on the page. They all have the same `.class` names and no unique `#id`.

```
const tableCount = await page.$$eval('table', (tables) => tables.length);
console.log(tableCount)
19
```

Comment: it depends on which table you need. do you know its number?

Answer (score 0):

Use https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-child/

```html
<section class="grid">
  <article class="module">One</article>
  <article class="module">Two</article>
  <article class="module">Three</article>
  <article class="module">Four</article>
  <article class="module">Five</article>
</section>
```

````css
.module:nth-child(4n) {
  margin-right: 0;
}```
````